# In unit testing loosely typed languages, should the return type of methods be checked?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, unit-testing

In strongly typed languages such as Java, there is no need to explicitly check the type of object returned since the code cannot compile if the return types do not match method signature.  Ex.  You cannot return a boolean when an integer is expected.

In loosely typed languages such as Ruby, JavaScript, Python, etc.,  anything can be returned.  Would it make sense to write a unit test that checks the type of object returned from a method?  This, in my opinion, will ensure that a boolean is returned where a boolean is expected.

Is it even necessary to have the Unit test below?

=============================

An attempt at Ruby example:

first_module.rb:

```
module FirstModule
  TypeA = Struct.new(
    :prop1,
    :prop2)

  self.create_type_a
    TypeA.new(
      'prop1Val',
      'prop2Val')
  end
end
```

type_a_repository.rb:

```
module TypeARepository
  def self.function_to_test
    FirstModule.create_type_a  # This will return TypeA object
  end
end
```

type_a_repository_spec.rb:

```
RSpec.describe '' do
  describe '' do
    before do
      allow(FirstModule).to receive(:create_type_a)
          .and_return(FirstModule.create_type_a)
    end

    it '' do
      result = TypeARepository.function_to_test
      expect(result).to be_a(FirstModule::TypeA) # is this necessary?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In some cases, your assertions would implicitly test for type. For the `boolean` example, if you do something like `expect(myVariable).toEqual(true)` you are testing for type as well as the value. For objects or collections, if you are testing properties of the object or accessing items from the collection in the test, often that's a pretty good implicit test. I'd say it depends on the situation.

Comment: This is quite a vague / opinion based question.... My answer would be: It depends. But usually no. I would presume that the purpose of such a test is to check how your functions/object interact with one another in the wider application - to which my answer would be: You should write some integration tests, checking critical paths.

Comment: Can you add an example? I would argue that tests usually expect that certain values will be returned by a method, doesn't that implicitly test the type of the returned value too?

Comment: Can you define *precisely* what you mean by "loosely typed languages"? That term does not have a widely-agreed definition (unlike e.g. "static typing" or "manifest typing" or "explicit typing"), and according to most definitions I have seen, Ruby is *not* not loosely typed. Also, can you specify what *precisely* you mean by "checking the return type"? In Ruby, "type" is a concept that exists mostly in the programmer's head, so it's actually very hard to check for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you employ [programming by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) then the answer's usually "no", as in so long as the return value meets expected criteria, which are often really loose, then you can't complain.

For example:

```
# Adds together zero or more integer values and returns the sum
def sum(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0,:+)
end
```

When testing you'd do something like this:

```
assert_equal 0, sum
assert_equal 1, sum(1)
assert_equal 0, sum(1, -1)
```

Now what happens when you supply non-integer values?

```
sum('1')
# => Exception: String can't be coerced into Integer
```

The original contract didn't specify that as a valid use case, so the exception is warranted. If you want to expand the scope:

```
# Adds together zero or more numerical values and returns the sum
def sum(*numbers)
  numbers.map(&:to_i).inject(0,:+)
end
```

Now you can add together non-integer values:

```
assert_equal 6, sum(1, 2.0, '3')
```

Note that the whole time so long as the result passes the assert test you're satisfied. In Ruby `6.0`, `6`, and `"6"` are all different, non-equivalent, so there's no worry about getting the wrong type.

This may not be true in other languages so you may need to be more specific about your results. The important thing is to avoid literal tests if you can, and instead just use the result *as intended*. For example:

```
assert_equal "this is amazing", "this is " + amazing_string_result
```

So long as whatever comes out of `amazing_string_result` can be appended to a string and the result matches that's an acceptable response.

This often comes into play when you want literal `true` or `false` instead of some *truthful* value like `1`:

```
assert_true some_method?(:value)
```

Where if that returns a *truthful* but non-literal `true` value the contract is broken and it fails.

Remember, there's an unlimited amount of paranoia you can have. Are you sure your values add up properly?

```
assert_equal 6, 1 + 2 + 3
assert_equal 6, 6
assert_equal 6, '6'.to_i
assert_true true
```

At some point you're no longer testing your code but are instead running regression tests on the programming language or hardware you're executing this code on, which is a complete waste of time if you're writing tests for *your code*.

The best unit tests:

- Demonstrate how the code is supposed to be used by clearly describing the expectations for inputs and outputs.
- Identify and verify behaviour at any and all boundary conditions relevant to the problem being solved.
- Illustrate failure modes when the code is used in improper ways that *must* be expressly disallowed.
- Avoid demonstrating all of the infinite ways in which the code will not work.